# MAGENTO 2 Customer grid backend "no such entity" issue

Tags: magento2, customer, no-such-entity-exception

after deleting a store in my Magento 2, if I go to the customer page I find the error "No Such Entity". On the DB there are all and even changing the website_id, store_id and created_in I do not solve anything.
I tried everything, reindex, deploy, upgrade but nothing ...
I also noticed that if I delete all the clients from the DB, I visualize the structure with the header but without any records. As soon as I add a customer, the NO SUCH ENTITY error appears
Solutions ?????

Comment: Can you show the error detail?